# scraping : nested url data scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a website name https://www.grohe.com/in
In that page i want to get one type of bathroom faucets https://www.grohe.com/in/25796/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/grandera/
In that page there are multiple products/related products.I want to get each product url and scrap the data.For that i wrote like this...

My items.py file looks like

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class ScrapytestprojectItem(Item):
    producturl=Field()
    imageurl=Field()
    description=Field()
```

spider code is

```
import scrapy
from ScrapyTestProject.items import ScrapytestprojectItem
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nestedurl"
    allowed_domains = ['www.grohe.com']
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.grohe.com/in/7780/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
    for divs in response.css('div.viewport div.workspace div.float-box'):
        item = {'producturl': divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract(),
                'imageurl': divs.css('a img::attr(src)').extract(),
                'description' : divs.css('a div.text::text').extract() + divs.css('a span.nowrap::text').extract()}
        next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item})
```

when i ran the scrapy 
**scrapy crawl nestedurl -o nestedurl.csv
**
empty file created.
The console is

```
2017-02-15 18:03:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on    127.0.0.1:6024
2017-02-15 18:03:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET  https://www.grohe.com/in/7780/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/>  (referer: None)
2017-02-15 18:03:13 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET   https://www.grohe.com/in/7780/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/>   (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-        packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in     process_spider_output
     for x in result:
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
      return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-     packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
   return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
 File    "/home/pradeep/ScrapyTestProject/ScrapyTestProject/spiders/nestedurl.py",    line 15, in parse
   next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py",    line 72, in urljoin
   return urljoin(get_base_url(self), url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 261, in urljoin
   urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 143, in urlparse
  tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 176, in urlsplit
     cached = _parse_cache.get(key, None)
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
    2017-02-15 18:03:13 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
   2017-02-15 18:03:13 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
          {'downloader/request_bytes': 253,
          'downloader/request_count': 1,
       'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
          'downloader/response_bytes': 31063,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
        'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
            'finish_reason': 'finished',
        'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 12, 33, 13, 396542),
        'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
          'log_count/ERROR': 3,
          'log_count/INFO': 7,
          'response_received_count': 1,
       'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
          'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
          'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
          'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
           'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 12, 33, 11, 568424)}
          2017-02-15 18:03:13 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think item `divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract()` sometimes returns a list which when used in urljoin leads which causes urlparse to crash as it can not hash a list.

Answer (score 0):

URL is not being generated correctly.

You should enable logging, and log some messages to debug your code.

```
import scrapy, logging
from ScrapyTestProject.items import ScrapytestprojectItem
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nestedurl"
    allowed_domains = ['www.grohe.com']
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.grohe.com/in/7780/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
    for divs in response.css('div.viewport div.workspace div.float-box'):
        item = {'producturl': divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract(),
                'imageurl': divs.css('a img::attr(src)').extract(),
                'description' : divs.css('a div.text::text').extract() + divs.css('a span.nowrap::text').extract()}
        next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])

        logging.info(next_page ) # see what it prints in console.

        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item})
```

Comment: generated url is like '/in/8257/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/product-details/?product=19408-G145&color=000&material=19408000' it shoud be append to 'www.grohe.in' url then it makes sence

Comment: loger info       [https://www.grohe.com/in/8257/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/product-details/?product=33623-G145&color=000&material=33623000]       ....sameway multiple urls are formed

Comment: No, you can manually join URL like `"www.grohe.in" + item['producturl']`

Answer (score 0):

```
    item = {'producturl': divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract(),  # <--- issue here
            'imageurl': divs.css('a img::attr(src)').extract(),
            'description' : divs.css('a div.text::text').extract() + divs.css('a span.nowrap::text').extract()}
    next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])  # <--- here item['producturl'] is a list
```

To fix this use `.extract_first('')`:

```
    item = {'producturl': divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract_fist(''),
            'imageurl': divs.css('a img::attr(src)').extract_first(''),
            'description' : divs.css('a div.text::text').extract() + divs.css('a span.nowrap::text').extract()}
    next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])
```

Comment: In my spider code i used .extract_first()/.extract_first(' ')  .still same output no change.samething i tested in scrapy shell with .extract() it self.it seems good

Comment: producturl is like ---->    /in/8257/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/product-details/?product=19408-G145&color=000&material=19408000                        after that we form the link as  'https://www.grohe.com/in/8257/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/product-details/?product=19408-G145&color=000&material=19408000'